# How to filter Subscribers based on array of tags in Loopabck

Tags: node.js, postgresql, loopbackjs, loopback

I've two models - **subscribers** and **tags**

Sample data:

```
{
 subscribers: [
  {
   name: "User 1",
   tags: ["a","b"] 
  },
  {
   name: "User 2",
   tags: ["c","d"] 
  }
 ]
}
```

I want to filter subscribers based on their tags.

- If I give `a` and `b` tags, User 1 should list
- If I give `a` and `c` tags, 
  both User 1 and User 2 should list

Here is what I tried:

**Method 1:**

`tags` is a column in `subscribers` model with array data type

```
/subscribers/?filter={"where":{"tags":{"inq":["a","b"]}}} // doesn't work
```

**Method 2:**

Created a separate table `tags` and set `subscribers` has many `tags`.

```
/subscribers/?filter={"where":{"tags":{"inq":["a","b"]}}} // doesn't work
```

How can I achieve this in Loopback without writing custom methods?

I've **Postgresql** as the connector

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in the [loopback docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Where-filter.html#inq) you should use `inq` not `In`

> The **inq** operator checks whether the value of the specified property matches any of the values provided in an array. The general syntax is:
>   {where: { property: { **inq**: [val1, val2, ...]}}}

From this:

/subscribers/?filter={"where":{"tags":{**"In"**:["a","b"]}}}

To this:

/subscribers/?filter={"where":{"tags":{**"inq"**:["a","b"]}}}

Comment: this question is specific to Loopback

Comment: @GijoVarghese i've misunderstood your request and updated my answer accordingly

Comment: That doesn't work. In order to make it work the `tags` column should not be array

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a hack, using Regex! it's not a performant solution, but it works!!

`{ "where": { "tags": { "regexp": "a|b" } } }`